# How to show results for a specific search scope in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, I created several new search scopes to different document library locations, but get no results returned no matter which one i use.  I even created a search scope to search "all content", attached it to my search box web part, and still no results!

What would be a cause for this?

I notice that when i remove the &s=myscope, from the URL, the results then show, but as soon as I place &s=myscope back on it, i get no results.  What should I be debugging or checking for?...

- I've waited 15 minutes for the scope to krawl
- Indexing Site Content for the sub site, is set to yes
- The search box web part is connected to the correct search scope
  group

This is driving me crazy...

Thanks for any help!

---

<s>I even created a search scope to search "all content", attached it to my search box web part, and still no results!</s>

It works when i set the scope to "all content" - just discovered that!  But not when I try to set a web address to specific folder...

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the difference between the behaviors, "Include" and "Require" helped.  Also the web address to filter the scope too, is potentially sensitive?  I included an "https" in the beginning of the URL, because the site I use, also uses "https".  But then I tried it out with "http"...So as a final verdict, by using "Include" and "http://", my scope crawled all the items in my specific directory and I now get results!